# Remove search form from search results page

Tags: theming, search

I have a search box in a sidebar and I'm happy with it. I don't want Drupal to output another one on the results page. So far I've managed to remove it with the following code

```
function mythemename_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    if(array_key_exists('page', $variables)) {
        if(array_key_exists('content', $variables['page'])) {
            if(array_key_exists('system_main', $variables['page']['content'])) {
                if(array_key_exists('search_form', $variables['page']['content']['system_main'])) {
                    unset($variables['page']['content']['system_main']['search_form']);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but it doesn't look very clean to me. Is there another way?

Answer (score 5):

Write a form alter:

```
function module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == "search_form") {
     $form['#type'] = 'hidden';
  }
}
```

Comment: Sure, but that requires a module. This should be a templating issue.

Comment: @Morpheu5, you can call the function `mytheme_form_alter` and put it in template.php of your theme, thus you have a possibility not to use any module

Comment: @Alex unfortunately, no matter how hard I tried, mytheme_form_alter did never get registered and called.

Comment: Above code doesn't work. You need to change the 3rd line into `$form['#access'] = FALSE;`

Answer (score 4):

There is the exact [same question in drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/968002), and your solution seems to be similar - but with more code - [with this](http://drupal.org/node/968002#comment-4573218). Keep in mind that there is always the option of using css to target specific elements and make them not display (i.e. display: none;).

Comment: Using isset() instead of !empty() and hide() instead of unset() is probably better practice.

Comment: Hiding stuff via css has the obvious disadvantage of leaving it in the code, which is something you don't want if you're going to target screen readers and stuff like that. hide() seems to be better than unset() and I'm probably going for that, but I'm still surprised there's no easier way to control such an important feature.

Answer (score 3):

`search_view()` is the function that builds the search page. So Another way is to implement the`hook_menu_alter()` and change page callback from `search_view` to your own function. You can copy the `search_view`'s body to your function and remove the following line:

`$build['search_form'] = drupal_get_form('search_form', NULL, $keys, $info['module']);`

Of course, this also doesn't seem to be very clean!

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 7 You can use hook_page_alter: http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/drupal%21modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_page_alter/7

```
/**
 * implements hook_page_alter()
 *
 * Alter the page output before render.
*/
function NAME_OF_YOUR_THEME_page_alter(&$page) {
  // kpr($page); //use this to find the item you want to remove - you need the devel running.
  // Remove the search form from the search results page.
  if (arg(0) == 'search') {
    if (!empty($page['content']['system_main']['search_form'])) {
      hide($page['content']['system_main']['search_form']);
    }
  }
}
```